# Amazon Beanstalk autoscaling and EBS instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-ebs, autoscaling

My questions is pretty straightforward, I have an Amazon Elastic Beanstalk application and I want to attach an existing EBS instance everytime that my elastic autoscaling creates a new instance.

How can I do that?

THanks.

Comment: Do you mean you have a bank of prepared, unattached EBS instances ready to be picked up by your eb app?

Comment: Let me show you the case: My instance became unhealthy and the load balancer destroyed it, creating a new instance, but the EBS store was not attached to the new one. This is one scenario.

Comment: The other scenario is sharing the same EBS between multiple instances, but I have just read that this is impossible, but at least I want to cover my first scenario

Answer (score 2):

If you are talking about the "main" EBS from which your app instance was booting, then as far as I know, the elastic load balancer destroys that EBS when the instance is terminated. It isn't saved. It sounds like this is what you are describing.

If you are talking about a different EBS which is attached to the instance in addition to (and after) the one from which it is booting, then it should be easy enough to re-attach it to the new instance by using elastic beanstalk configuration files. I assume this kind of EBS could be saved. It's an interesting solution for ensuring that data persists between instances in some ways, but like you said, an EBS can't be mounted by multiple instances simultaneously.

I think most people use S3 or a separate instance(s) with an NFS (that's what I do) to keep data that shouldn't die with an unhealthy instance.

Comment: What is NFS? I will google it, but your point of view can be useful

Comment: Ideally you want to design your application so that important data is not stored on individual instances.

Answer (score 0):

You need script that will on bootstrap of new ec2 instance will attach ebs. You need to add yo  your bundle .ebextentions, create config file which will contains command for mounting of ebs to instance.

Following links will be useful:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/customize-containers-ec2.html
http://www.hudku.com/blog/configuration-setup-customizing-aws-elastic-beanstalk/